# A subset of a subset of a subset of a subset of a set of $\{1,2,\cdots,10\}$

Tags: combinatorics

> - There is a set of $10$ first natural numbers, $S = \{1,2,\cdots,10\}$.
> - Alice picks a subset of it, say $A \subseteq S$.
> - Bob picks a subset of it, say $B \subseteq A$.
> - Charlie picks a subset of it, say $C \subseteq B$.
> - Dave picks a subset of it, say $D \subseteq C$.

How many different ways of their picking are there?
i.e. How many different tuples of $\langle A,B,C,D \rangle$ are there?

Comment: Subsets, or proper subsets? (i.e. is the null set valid? Is the full set valid?)

Comment: is this a math question rather than a puzzle???

Comment: They are subsets, i.e. it is possible for $A = S$ and also $A = \{\}$. Idk if this is a good puzzle here because I guess the way to solve this is pretty fun as a math puzzle. Tho it's perfectly fine if it's considered off-topic if people say so.. ^^

Comment: sorry i have to -1 this as this is off-topic...

Comment: @Omega do you think this is not a puzzle?

Comment: Seeing the answer, I would consider this a maths puzzle as there is a clever and quick way to solve it which is not immediately obvious.

Comment: @someone i believe that this is not a puzzle. the answer is good, however, so i upvoted it.

Comment: +1 to the question so more people will see Jaap's amazing answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> For each element we can choose the last person to have it in their set. There are $5$ possibilities for each element, namely None, Alice, Bob, Charlie, or Dave. Each element is independent of all the others. Therefore there are $5^{10}=9765625$ ways to arrange the elements amongst the sets.
>
>  Here is a nice way to look at it.
>  Imagine that A chooses some of the 10 items.
>  B now chooses some of A's items and takes them from her.
>  C now takes some of B's items from him.
>  D now takes some of C's items from him.
>  Any arrangement of the items can be the result. So each item can be with any of the 4 people, or with none of them.
>  The same is happening in this question, except that the people share the items they took.

Comment: Wow, excellent solution.  So much easier to compute than the complex sums of sums of sums...

Comment: Indeed, this is how it's done! :)